# Confused about truth in standard models vs non-standard models

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

So let's say I have a set of sentences $T$, true in my standard model $\mathfrak{A}$. I construct the consequences of $T$, $Cn(T)$. For any non-standard model $\mathfrak{B}$, it has to be the case that $T$ and thus $Cn(T)$ are true in $\mathfrak{B}$, correct?

Comment: I think the answer is "yes", but I'm not sure quite why you're asking, which makes me think I might be misunderstanding the question. Could you please add a little more to the question?  Also - by $\text{Cn}(T)$ you mean the set $\{ \phi : T \vdash \phi\}$, right?

Comment: What does “standard model” mean here? Of Peano arithmetic?

Comment: @CarlMummert I think you understand it correctly, I understand the question is trivial. I think I just started to doubt my basic knowledge because I was stuck on a problem. I think I just realized the reason why I was stuck was trying to prove something independent of some sentence à la Cantor.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Although I don't believe it's relevant to the question, I am working specifically with $\mathbb{N}$ as my standard model.

Comment: As long as $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies $T$, it will satisfy $\text{Cn}(T)$. That is essentially the statement of the soundness theorem.

Comment: @CarlMummert Thank you, this was my thinking since anything in $Cn(T)$ follows from $T$, not really anything to do with the specific model, correct?

Comment: Exactly - it is a general property of the proof system, that if a set of formulas are all true then so is anything provable from them.  That works in any model, standard or not.

Comment: I am also unsure what you are asking, but the answer depends on what notion of consequence you are using. If it is syntactic/deductive (what is derivable in your theory, although no theory is mentioned here) then yes, in any model where $T$ hold so do the consequences. But if you mean [semantic consequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Proofs_and_models), this is no longer the case.

Comment: @CarlMummert I just say your edit which might change things according to Conifold. I mean $Cn(T)=\{\varphi|T\models\varphi\}$.

Comment: Well, $\{ \phi : T \vdash \phi\}$ is the same as $\{ \phi : T \vDash \phi\}$ by some combination of the soundness and completeness theorems, so either of those is OK with me. I was afraid you might have some other idea in mind. For example, if you meant $\{ \phi : \mathcal{A} \vDash \phi\}$ for some model $\mathcal{A}$, this might be very different than $\{\phi : \mathcal{B} \vDash \phi\}$ for some other model $\mathcal{B}$, even if both satisfy $T$.

Comment: @CarlMummert OK this definitely clears up some of my main confusion. I was trying to show a sentence $\sigma$ followed semantically (?) from a set of sentences $T$ (i.e $T\models\sigma$), and was unable to show it. I was thinking that it was obvious from my mental image of the model $\mathfrak{A}$, but the method of proof I had relied on the model in mind being the standard one. The proof would not have worked with the non-standard model $\mathfrak{B}$ in mind. This is where the question, _Do standard and non-standard models have to have the same set of consequences?_ arose.

Comment: @CarlMummert So I guess to sum up, the proof I should write for $T\models\sigma$ should really just rely on everything in $T$, **BUT** as a self-check, this proof should work for any model, standard or non-standard (i.e any structure $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $\mathfrak{A}\models T$). Is this a correct analysis?

Comment: Yes, any proof that $T \vDash \phi$ that uses models will have to work for every model, standard or nonstandard.

Comment: How would your proof work for any model, standard or non-standard, unless it is just a syntactic derivation $T\vdash\phi$? Semantic consequences of $\mathfrak{U}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ can be different even if both of them $\vDash T$. It does not seem plausible that you can give a semantic proof that works uniformly enough in every model that $\vDash T$. So if your proof needs to "have a model in mind" I suspect that there is something amiss in it.

Comment: @Conifold People give semantic proofs that statements are consequences of theories all the time. As a silly example, if you wanted to show Lagrange's four-square theorem was provable in PA, you probably wouldn't attack it with sequent calculus, rather would verify that the usual informal proof only appealed to the fact that $\mathbb N$ is a model of PA, and nothing about $\mathbb N$ outside that.  Also, semantic and syntactic consequences *of a theory* are the same thing (in first order logic). Things that are true in a structure aren't usually called semantic consequences of the structure.

Comment: @Conifold (Regarding the last point, it seems OP was using the term like this as well... this is what the last couple exchanges with Carl seems to have cleared up.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen What bothers me is how would one, while working with a model, verify that one only used that it is a model of PA? Unless one is just using PA axioms and their (syntactic) consequences, in which case the model is redundant (other than to help intuition). A simpler case of this would be working with a Euclidean diagram. One verifies that one did not use a property of it which is specific to the figure (as in all-triangles-are-isosceles and other fallacies) by producing a proof in which the figure is redundant. It doesn't have to be formal, but it wouldn't be semantic exactly.

Comment: @Conifold: I completely agree with your concerns, and I think that in most cases the seemingly "semantic" proof is just a wrapper for a syntactic proof. One more complicated possibility for a method that isn't so trivially syntactic: use a model-theoretic proof to show that some other theory $S$ is conservative over your theory $T$, then prove the original result in $S$, and finally apply the conservation result to know the result is provable in $T$.

Comment: @Conifold One reasonable summary of the completeness theorem is “models are redundant.” The happier flip side is “syntactic proof is sufficient.” The key difference is we use the truth of the axioms and argue informally from that. The completeness theorem and the fact that some deductive systems (e.g. natural deduction) closely mirror informal reasoning definitely make it a blurry line between ‘convincing yourself a formal proof exists’ and ‘verifying that the informal argument only uses the axioms.’ But consider situations where completeness fails, like second order logic with full semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key question here 'is standard model of what?' If it is a complete theory, e.g. $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb N),$ then any collection of sentences true in $\mathbb N$ is true in any nonstandard model of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb N).$ If it is not a complete theory, e.g. PA, then this is no longer the case unless the sentences of $T$ are all consequences of PA. I guess that's the key point... all consequences of PA are true in all models of PA. Whereas any sentence that is consistent with, but not a consequence of PA is true in some models of PA but not others. (this is either tautological or a consequence of completeness/soundness theorem, depending on whether we mean semantic or syntactic consequence).

For instance, the Godel sentence $G$ and $\operatorname{Con}(PA)$ are both true in $\mathbb N,$ but there are nonstandard models of PA in which they are false. So $T=\{\operatorname{Con}(PA)\}$ is a theory whose consequences all hold in $\mathbb N$ (moreover its consequences modulo PA all hold), but there are nonstandard models of PA in which some of the consequences are not satisfied, namely $\operatorname{Con}(PA)$ itself.

Comment: The theory I was working with is complete. I guess I was stuck so I started questioning my understanding of how semantic proofs work, and realized I didn't really fully understand them. I was trying to decide whether some set of sentences $T$ semantically entail a sentence $\sigma$. It was unnecessary for me to make a whole post about it I should have checked my definitions and I would have answered the question for myself.

Comment: A set off sentences $T$ logically implies (semantically) a sentence $\sigma$, $T\models\sigma$ iff for every structure $\mathfrak{A}$, $\models_{\mathfrak{A}}T$ implies $\models_{\mathfrak{A}}\sigma$. This definition right here answers my question, but so did Carl with his patience.